# I tried to use hapi/Joi but its showed error, how can it be solved?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I am new for Node.js, I used `hapi/Joi` for validation but it shows the following error how can i solve it:

```
const Joy = require('@hapi/joi');

const schema = {
  username: Joy.string().min(6).required(),
  email: Joy.string().min(6).required(),
  password: Joy.string().min(6).required()
}

router.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  const Validation = Joy.validate(req.body, schema);
  res.send(Validation);
})
```

I run the program and it shows the following error:

> TypeError: Joy.validate is not a function

how can I solve the issue, please provide a solution.

Comment: version of `JOI`?

Comment: I am using 17.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to validate it using schema.validate().

```
const schema = {
  username: Joy.string().min(6).required(),
  email: Joy.string().min(6).required(),
  password: Joy.string().min(6).required()
};

schema.validate(req.body);
```